# PHP Delete File from Dropdown

Tags: php, html

I have a dropdown list populated with files pulled from a directory using the PHP listed below and am trying to figure out how I can delete them using a delete button in the form when they're selected.

```
<input type="hidden" name="Action" value="EDIT" /><input type="hidden" name="Selection"  id="Selection" value="-1"><div>Below is the list of your saved codes. To edit your codes, select it from the list.</div>
<select size="1" name="CodeList" id="CodeList">
<?php
   $directory = $directory = 'users/' . $_SESSION['username'];
   $filesContents = Array();
   $files = scandir( $directory ) ;

   foreach( $files as $file )
  {
   if ( ! is_dir( $file ) )
  {
   $filesContents[$file] = file_get_contents($directory , $file);
  echo "<option>" . $file . "</option>";
  }
   }
   ?>
   </select>
```

Updating code as I go.

```
<?php
   session_start();
    $directory = $directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/users/' . $_SESSION['username'];
    $file_to_delete = $_POST['CodeList'];
    if ( unlink ($directory.'/'.$file_to_delete) ) {
      echo $file_to_delete . " deleted.";
   } else {
echo "Error.";
}
?>
```

***edited and updated code***

Now says Warning: unlink(/myhome/root/public_html/users/Addiction/) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in /home/revo/public_html/evo/avdeleteprocess.php on line 5
Error.

So its found the right folder, just not finding the file from the dropdown list selection.

**Also edited to add** I ran a var_dump($_POST) right after my delete script to see what it was pulling as the value of POST and it came back with: Error.array(1) { ["Action"]=> string(6) "Delete" }

Comment: Actually it didn't even find `$_SESSION['username']`, where you created the session?

Comment: I see that now, it stopped apparently at finding just users/ I'm not exactly sure how to make it find the proper folder then the correct file in the dropdown.

Comment: I added in session_start(); just in case at the top of my php script and it changed the error to: Warning: unlink(/) [function.unlink]: Is a directory in /home/revo/public_html/evo/avdeleteprocess.php on line 6
Error.

Comment: Right. What I mean before is, if you don't create the session username, like: `$_SESSION['username'] = 1;`, for example, it will always return empty.

Comment: Right. That makes sense on why it wouldn't find it. Now I just need to figure out why its not finding the file.

Comment: Actually $_POST['$file'] syntax is wrong. Take a look in my answer, maybe it could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your code with a `form` tag. Also, the $_POST needs to get the name of your select (in this case), so:

**form.php:**

```
<form action="avdeleteprocess.php" method="post">
<select size="1" name="CodeList" id="CodeList">
<?php
   $directory = 'users/' . $_SESSION['username'];
   $filesContents = Array();
   $files = scandir( $directory ) ;

   foreach( $files as $file )
  {
   if ( ! is_dir( $file ) )
  {
   $filesContents[$file] = file_get_contents($directory , $file);
  echo "<option value='".$file."'>" . $file . "</option>";
  }
   }
   ?>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" name="Action" value="DELETE" />
</form>
```

**avdeleteprocess.php:**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $directory = 'users/'.$_SESSION['username'].'/';
  //here you can even check if user selected 'delete' option:
  if($_POST['Action'] == "DELETE"){
      $file_to_delete = $_POST['CodeList'];
      if(unlink($directory.'/'.$file_to_delete))
         echo $file_to_delete." deleted.";
      else
         echo "Error deleting file ".$file_to_delete;
  }
  if($_POST['Action'] == "SAVE"){
      ...
  }
?>
```

Comment: changed that, and it still tells me: Warning: unlink(users/Addiction/) [function.unlink]: Is a directory in /home/revo/public_html/evo/avdeleteprocess.php on line 6
Error.

Comment: Where is your 'delete' button? Do you wrapped your code into a `form` tag?

Comment: I did, yes, and the delete button is below the main form which might be the issue you can see the entire coding here with everything updated: https://jsfiddle.net/076borbL/1/

Comment: It seems we missed the file value in `option`. Take a look in my updated code. Also, when you run the code, the file names appear on the select dropdown?

Comment: I changed that in my updated coding which was in the fiddle. I will try it with the delete button there in that form and that delete code just to see if it works, however the form is also used to save files when they input information (the same files the dropdown pulls from) not sure if that can be done on the same form. if not, I can create two pages and forms. will test this.

Comment: Hmm yes, but maybe you want to use that way of adding an `if($_POST['Action'] == "...){` on your process page.

Comment: wow, that did it. Missing the fact the dropdown wasn't wrapped in form and putting the delete button on the same form. however I'm not sure how to write it to have a save button that saves information they put in the data in the same form and have that delete button there as well based on what file they select. can I combine process forms (put my save and delete depending on which input they press) in the same .php file with those commands?

Comment: and I can clarify that question or start a new one if need be. Just need to know if I can put like if($_POST['ACTION'] == "SAVE"){ somewhere on there and then my save script beneath to run both save and delete from the same form

Comment: Yes, you can. I updated my answer now with an example of it, you just need to put your code into the `if($_POST['ACTION'] == "SAVE"){`, or even add more ifs, as needed. To not extend the conversation here, if this doesn't work you may want to close this quesion and open a new one with the last changes :)

Comment: Will do, and thank you Dimas, for all of your help. You taught me alot tonight and if I can't get that to work, I'll post up another question, god bless.

Answer (score 1):

Your form will not be submit using

```
<button type="button">Delete</button>
```

Try

```
<button type="submit">Delete</button>
```

Comment: I completely missed that, thank you, and am unsure if my php for getting the correct file that's being displayed from the dropdown to delete is right but will be testing that soon.